# JProfiler is stuck at VM initialized Phase

Tags: jprofiler

I am trying to connect to remote JVM and passing following JVM flag:

```
-agentpath:/home/vishalgarg/jprofiler11.1.4/bin/linux-x64/libjprofilerti.so=port=8849,nowait
```

However, the process is getting stuck at VM initialized phase. Can anyone help me in understanding the root cause?

- JProfiler> Protocol version 63
- JProfiler> Java 8 detected.
- JProfiler> Don't wait for frontend to connect.
- JProfiler> 64-bit library
- JProfiler> Starting up without initial configuration.
- JProfiler> Listening on port: 8849.
- JProfiler> Enabling native methods instrumentation.
- JProfiler> Can retransform classes.
- JProfiler> Can retransform any class.
- JProfiler> Native library initialized
- JProfiler> VM initialized

Comment: By "getting stuck", do you mean that the process really hangs? The "nowait" option means that the profiling agent is loaded and does not wait for a connection from the JProfiler UI.

Comment: yes, I meant process hangs and there is no progress.

Comment: Can you get a thread dump from the process with the jstack tool in the JDK?